# Is it possible to tether internet on the iPhone to an Ethernet attached device?

Tags: iphone, ethernet, tethering, television

I have a hotspot connection on my iPhone 7 Plus phone that is extremely slow. The Internet on my phone is extremely fast. When I connect a device the connection is very slow. The device is a smart TV. I have an option to connect an Ethernet cable to my TV. I have unlimited data and hotspot plan.

Is there any way to use my phone hotspot to connect to TV 
via Ethernet and will the connection be faster?

Comment: Done   I added my phone model.

Comment: Ok thanks but how will that work ? Lighting to the USB port on my tv ? How do I connect the usb to Ethernet ?

Comment: But the usb Ethernet adapter have the same usb plug as the lightning USB adapter there’s isn’t a usb plug to plug the usb side from the lightening cable.